# disable kwallet kubuntu kde 20.04

Tags: kde, kwallet

I get asked to unlock the keyring (kwallet) every time I open vscode.  How do I have the kring work with vscode .  I tried disabling kwallet once before and I lost all of my passwords in chrome and network.

Normal keyring suggestions just don't work with kde.
I never understood the purpose of keyrings.. it should work with your login and end there.

Keyring for vscode works in Gnome but not kde they say.
Is there a way to have chrome save my passwords and like my phone does without kwallet?  When I was on eOS (ubuntu 18.04) , I just set the password to "" and everything was fine.  Is there a way to do that with kwallet?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable and disable the KDE wallet subsystem by doing the following:

1. In the Application Launcher, open "**KDE Wallet** *(KDE Wallet Configuration)*"
2. Uncheck the Box "Enable the KDE wallet subsystem"
3. Click "**OK**"

Comment: Now I lost all my passwords.  Basically it should remember things when I log in.  The keyring can do this and I'm ready to swap out kubuntu because of this wallet thing.

Comment: sorry.. I edited.. the problems like this are usually solved by installing seahorse and setting the password to nothing.. but I'm not clear how to do this for kwallet.  If I disable, then I don't have my passwords for netlogin

Comment: *"setting the password to nothing"* kdewallet actually works the exact same way. If you don't enter a master password, you won't be promoted for it when there is a call for a password stored in the wallet.

Comment: Let me try this tomorrow as well.  I did that too and had to reboot and it worked.  I'll edit your answer and mark as solved if okay tomorrow .  Much appreciated.. I'll also inform other places too that complained about this.

Comment: It still asked me for my password this morning.  Sometimes it does not ask right away.  Maybe there is a way to disable in vscode.  The feature is more annoying than it saves me time.. I only need password for when I push to the server which is one out o ten or so opens.

Comment: Maybe you have more than one wallet?  I suggest that you go thru every setting in both places: Kwalletmanager and KDE Wallet (Configuration).  Maybe "Close" and "Delete" any/all currently used wallet(s) and then create a new one but don't set a password to begin with.  (Deleting a wallet will delete passwords saved there) I think you must be missing a setting someplace, because this is not the intended behavior of the app.  If you're not missing anything then consider filing a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: I deleted the wallet (I think only one) but there were two folders listed.  I created another wallet called MyWallet with standard blowfish (less secure maybe easier?).  We will see how that works.. your help is appreciated.

Comment: Well.. I deleted the wallet and reset it to no pwd (again)..and vscode still wants my real password.. does not sound so good.  Maybe it is a hack virus.. no other app does this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import all your passwords from kde wallet to gnome keyring. After you do that, you can uninstall kde wallet. To uninstall kde wallet, type this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt remove kwalletmanager5;sudo apt autoremove kwalletmanager5;sudo apt purge kwalletmanager5
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Ooooo.. I will try this.. didn't think about this solution.  I eventually found out how to disable the keyring for vscode, but this is a viable solution.  I will mark this as the solution after testing.